# remove header and footer on landscape side

Tags: header-footer, lyx, landscape

I am trying to remove the header and footer from my landscaped side.

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{sidewaystable}
##table
\end{sidewaystable}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

will flip my page anbut removes the header/footer from all other pages. In addition it would be nice if the pagenumber would be written blow the table and not on the bottom of the "portrait format".

Thank you

Comment: you should use landscape package

Comment: try `\thispagestyle{empty}` to change the style for only one page

Comment: unfortunately \thispagestyle{empty} did not change anything

Comment: Provide MWE, which show your problem. Suggestion of @alaferg should work. And `\pagestyle{plain}` after `sidewaystable` is surplus.